# Remote Procedure Calls

Tags: java, c++, rpc

I am doing a Software Engineering course in which different teams are building different prototype subsystems of a big system (different subsystem of F35 Lightning aircraft!).

The problem is that teams can use different programming languages (like C++ and Java) depending upon what they are most comfortable in. However, these subsystems need to be communicating with each other (like radar needs to provide object corodinates to navigation and control). Hence we need to come up with a solution in which different modules can interact in real time.

Someone suggested XML-RPC and hence I was reading about it. After reading it I think it is used in server client architecture. Is this a good way of doing interprocess kind of communication? What are my options?

Any help would be appreciated.

regards,
Newbie

Comment: Are you told to use remote procedure calls, or is that just an option? I would recommend against it for simple message passing.

Comment: It is just an option. I am looking for a easy implementation that can allow me to communicate between different subsystems coded in different languages  and that are independent of each other...

Comment: Read up on the basics of TCP - this will be valuable! And you need to choose both a transport and a message format; these are often independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of options beside XML-RPC. For a short bullet-point comparison, take a look at:

- http://michaeldehaan.net/2008/07/17/xmlrpc-vs-rest-vs-soap-vs-all-your-rpc-options/

If your exchange is more data-oriented, [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) might be an alternative.

> Protocol Buffers are a way of encoding structured data in an efficient yet extensible format.

Personally, I would go for lightweight exchange format or method first since the components are considered prototypes. Something like REST or some custom message passing might be simple enough, yet sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked protocol buffer it looks like what I need. Just one question on the page you sent the link of. Can the person structure be instantiated in a C++ code and then can a Java code use values from it?

Comment: I am not exactly sure about your question, but I would think, that is one of the main points of this approach.

Comment: @Newbie: protobuf can be thought of as a multi-language-binding data serialization mechanism i.e. (i) You create a spec. (proto file) of your data structures (ii) Use it to code-gen code in language of your choice (could be C++, Java, what-have-you). (iii) Use generated code in your project for serialization/de-serialization. The data transport is independent of this mechanism i.e. how your data travels/moves from say a Java program to say a C++ program still has to be built independently (could be sockets, pipes, DBUS, etc).

Comment: [contd.]

OTOH, from what I have read/heard Thrift(http://thrift.apache.org/), besides providing the serialization mechanisms also provides RPC mechanisms for stub servers/clients and such. Another option to consider, I suppose.

Comment: If you like Protocol Buffers, you might also enjoy Facebook's [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) -- I think it's very cute and straight-to-the-point!

Answer (score 0):

If you are already familiar with XML, it can be a reasonable answer. An advantage of XML is that you don't have to worry about how different machines represent numbers. A disadvantage is the time it takes to keep converting numbers to text and back to numbers.